# Do I need a HTTPS for application that uses Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook, api, https

I'm building application that uses components from Facebook API, and there are certain requirements so app could go to review. I solved other requirements and I'm not quite sure do I need a HTTPS or it could work with HTTP just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need https if you create a Page/Tab App or a Canvas App. Check out the App Settings, those platforms specifically ask for a https link.

Working with http is fine, Token security is done best with `appsecret_proof`. It does not really matter if you use http or https for that.

That being said, having https is better than not having https. But the question was "do i need it", so...see my very first sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about facebook rules but:

- If the front end (javascript) has access to token to identification the user, maybe you should use https to protect that token.
- If you manipulate personal data of the user, then in a lot of country (in European countries for example) you have an obligation of protection.
- As https protect your website against unwanted modifications (ISP injecting Ads) and protect your users, in 2016 the question is less "should I use https?" and more "**do I have a good reason not to?**"